# SVG icon in PWA manifest.json - how to set it for all sizes?

Tags: icons, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Is there any way now to specify that an SVG icon in "manifest.json" for a PWA should be used for all possible sizes? (Chrome/chromium is my main target now. Firefox will hopefully follow.)

```
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "path-to-icon.svg",
            "purpose": "maskable any",
            "sizes: "???"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 37):

`"sizes": "any"`

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-sizes

Comment: Chrome dev tools tell me it has to be numbers.

Comment: It's supported in Firefox, will file a bug for Chrome. You can just put in some enormous number for Chrome.

Comment: @NotWoods Did you file a bug report? Link?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107123

Comment: Following up, that bug is marked as fixed. `"sizes": "any"` should work in Chrome now. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107123#c10 ✨

Answer (score 8):

"sizes": "any" didn't work for me. I used the following configuration:

```
{
    "src": "logo.svg",
    "sizes": "48x48 72x72 96x96 128x128 256x256 512x512",
    "type": "image/svg+xml",
    "purpose": "any"
}
```

Comment: Per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107123#c10, there *was* a problem in Chrome where "sizes" didn't work, but it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though `icons` has to be an array, so I use

```
        icons: [192, 256, 384, 512].map((x) => ({
            src: `${url}/icon.svg`,
            sizes: `${x}x${x}`,
            type: 'image/svg+xml',
            purpose: 'any'
        }))
```

(This is in a dynamically created manifest, so you could ahrd code the output if yours is static)